# Where Docker store volume on Windows or Mac?

Tags: docker

I created a docker volume

```
docker inspect mongodata                                                                                                [
{
    "CreatedAt": "2020-05-22T20:02:02Z",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Labels": {},
    "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/mongodata/_data",
    "Name": "mongodata",
    "Options": {},
    "Scope": "local"
}
```

]

Do you know where the docker stores this volume on Windows?

OS: Windows10 64x

Docker Desktop Version: 2.2.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker on Windows (and on Mac) use a small virtual machine to run Linux container and it's on this VM that you will find the data.

You can enter into this VM by running this container:

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1
```

For more information about this container: https://github.com/justincormack/nsenter1